# I use argparse to change path but if is it exists it using default path how can I fixed

Tags: python-3.x

when I try giving path as argument if is exists folder path is change to default path, but if not exists it creating! I don't know where the issue

```
if args.path_folder and not os.path.isdir(args.path_folder): #chick if path is valid 
    folder_path = args.path_folder
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        try:
            os.mkdir(folder_path)
        except OSError as e:
            print("Invalid path!,{}".format(e))
            exit(0)

elif args.save_here:
    folder_path = os.getcwd()
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        os.mkdir(folder_path)
        
else:
    exit(0)

####### argument option #######
parser.add_argument('--save-here', dest='save_here', action='store_true',
                        help="save files in current directory, this is default option")
parser.set_defaults(save_here=True)
    
# --save--folder #here will be change directory but default in current directory
        parser.add_argument('-d', '--folder-path', dest='path_folder', type=str, help='Change save files in different directory')
```

Comment: missing some code ? - there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)